# Adding items to Json based on other data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have some JSON data that I need to reorganize for a D3 stacked bar chart I am doing. Essentially I have a ename and total field in the JSON object. I need to take every unique ename in all of my JSON and make it a field for each object that takes the unique name for that node and the total for that name and make that the key/value pair and sets all the other unique names to 0 for that node.

So where a node currently looks something like this

```
{"id":"1", "month":"1", "total":"10", "year":"2012", "ename":"Jamie"}
```

after I have reorged it it would look something like this

```
{"id":"1", "month":"1", "total":"10", "year":"2012", "ename":"Jamie", "Jamie":"10", "Joe": "0", "Jeri":"0", "Ann":"0", "Ron":"0","Tim":"0"}
```

I'm trying to stack my bars based on each person who has shown up on specific dates.

I have some code that goes through the JSON to get the unique names here.

```
data.forEach(function(element, i){
getNames(data);
})


function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var uniq_enames = enames.filter( onlyUnique );

***This is where I am trying to add to my d****
data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.Date = new Date(d.year, d.month - 1);
  for(i=0; i < uniq_enames.length; i++){
    if(d.ename == uniq_enames[i]){
     var name = uniq_enames[i]


    }
  }
})
```

Where I am stuck is how to I add that name variable to be the key that I will use with the d.total as my value? Further (I'm assuming with a 2nd inner loop) how then do then on my else statement do the same thing for the other "name" keys setting them to a total of 0?

My original fiddle sets up the keys to 3 categories for the stack, I am trying to set up my keys to be all of the unique names (for reference the data here is hand done, when I get this working it will come from a service that could be any number of unique names)

Original Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/cuhqy8yj/

Fiddle I am trying to stack by names - https://jsfiddle.net/jamiebrs/6guh43yn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sooner than I posted this did I figure out what I wanted to do.

Here is how I add to the loop.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Date = new Date(d.year, d.month - 1);
  for(i=0; i < uniq_enames.length; i++){
    if(d.ename == uniq_enames[i]){
     var name = uniq_enames[i]
     d[name] = d.total    
    } else{
     var name = uniq_enames[i]
     d[name] = "0"
    }
  }
})
```